# XPATH for Importxml on google-sheets

Tags: xpath, google-sheets-formula

i am trying to extract some data from below web page to google-sheets using importxml formula.

http://tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&i=25244329144808274

the required field is shown in attached image.
[required record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJl4Z.png)

please help me on correct syntax. Thanks.

Comment: What you need is dynamically loaded using javascript, so `IMPORTXML` won't get it as it does not render js. You might want to look at how this is achieved in Python (just for example): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python. And then try to do the same in Google Script for you Sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, we can fetch the data from elsewhere. Just use :

```
=IMPORTXML("http://en.tsetmc.com/loader.aspx?ParTree=121C1412&inscode=25244329144808274";"//tr[./th[.='Quantity']]/following-sibling::tr[1]/td[2]")
```

Output :

[image: Stock]